# how can I insert into table using a function on redshift

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a simple function which gets 3 arguments and inserts them into a table (as a row).
Now I know that redshift doesn't support procedures, but enables python functions.

I have a python function which, when run outside redshift,  gets the job done.
Thing is how can I implement in into redhsift so when I call the function from a query it performs the same action ?

Here's the python code I'm using (which works fine **outside** redshift) :

```
import psycopg2

def insert_tab(arg1, arg2, arg3):
# Create connection to redshift
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect("dbname= 'dev' 
    host='something.redshift.amazonaws.com' "
                            "port= '5439' user= 'user' password= 'password'")
    con.autocommit = True
    cur = con.cursor()
except:
    print("Cannot connect to Database")

sql_statementy= "insert into table(a,b,c) values (%s, %s, %s)"
try:
    cur.execute(sql_statementy, (arg1, arg2, arg3))
except:
    print("insert into failed")
return
```

I run the python with

```
import write_table
write_table.insert_tab('a','b','c')
```

How do I implement this on redshift so I can call the function like

```
select insert_tab('a','b','d')
```

so it will work like a procedure ?

Comment: In addition to my reply below - perhaps there is a alternative way to tackle this which will work ok in redshift. Please can you describe your requirement? where does the data come from? what has to happen to it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it because UDFs are written in Python to process scalar values, arrays or objects, just like regular Python. You can't write SQL functions in Redshift. Though it might seem weird for people used to work in Postgres and other relational databases that support stored procedures, `select insert_tab('a','b','d')` is a wrapper for an OLTP environment that doesn't make any sense for analytics database.

Comment: This was true at the time but now Redshift supports procedures. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can actually write UDFs in either python or sql
(as of last week)
see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html

However there are certain limitations, including that they cannot read or write.
In fact, all they can do is return a single value.